# In SQL date function for before 2 months

Tags: mysql, sql

I mentioned database table structure below,

```
name, expired_date, address, payment_date
----------------------
name1, 2013/06/02, address1,2013/07/23
name2, 2013/06/02, address2,2013/07/23
name3, 2013/04/02, address3,2013/07/23
name4, 2013/05/02, address4,2013/07/23
name5, 2013/06/02, address5,2013/07/24
...
name6, 2013/06/02, address6,.....
```

In this table I update date in `yyyy/mm/dd` format . current month is April but I need after two records only.
For example I need 06 month records only.

I need SQL query for this.

Comment: Show your efforts please.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And which datatype is `expired_date` and `payment_date`?

Comment: we are using Mysql....datatype is date

Comment: Which field are you querying on? `expired_date` or 'payment_date`?

Comment: do you need to get records of April month from this tables ? Please explain your need properly.

Comment: no I need only June month records

Comment: Select [fields] from [yourtable] where Month([yourDateField]) = [Value, ex: for June : 6]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to query by expired_date:

Following query gets records after two months from current date:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName where expired_date>=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

If you specifically want records for June:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName where expired_date>='2013-06-01' AND expired_date<'2013-07-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
Select [fields] from [yourtable] where Month([yourDateField]) = [Value, ex: for June : 6]
```

Implement

I am assuming you want to check expired_date

```
Select * from Table1 where Month(expired_date) = 6
```

if you want to check year also then, assuming year is 2013.

```
Select * from Table1 where Month(expired_date) = 6 and Year(expired_date) = 2013
```